# Is it possible to detect whether a display:inline-block element has been squeezed to a new line by CSS so that I can assign new design to it?

Tags: html, css

I have a design like this:

```css
    .sub-tag-name {margin-right: 0;padding:2px 3px 2px 6px;border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;background:darkblue;color:white}
    .sub-tag-value {margin-left:0;padding:2px 3px 2px 6px;border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;color:darkblue}
    .sub-tag-name, .sub-tag-value {border: 2px solid #fff;display:inline-block;border-color:darkblue}
    .sub-tag-pair {font-size:36px;margin-right:5px;padding:3px;display:inline-block}
```

```html
<div class="sub-tag-pair">
<div class="sub-tag-name">Name</div><div class="sub-tag-value">Bob</div>
</div>


<div class="sub-tag-pair">
<div class="sub-tag-name">Name</div><div class="sub-tag-value">Blah blah .... blah blah ..... test test tset ...A vert vert long name that might break the line on mobile</div>
</div>
```

The pair of `divs` combines a tag design and it looks good on most desktop devices. However, on some mobile devices, the room for one row is not enough so it will break into two rows.

I'm okay with the line-break issue but I want to apply new design for this case. Is there any way I can do it with pure CSS?

Thanks

Comment: Using CSS? No. Using JS? Yes.

Comment: what new design you want to apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inline-flex` instead `inline-block` might suits better your needs:

```css
.sub-tag-name {
  margin-right: 0;
  padding: 2px 3px 2px 6px;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  background: darkblue;
  color: white;
}

.sub-tag-value {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: 2px 3px 2px 6px;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  color: darkblue
}

.sub-tag-name,
.sub-tag-value {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-color: darkblue
}

.sub-tag-pair {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="sub-tag-pair">
  <div class="sub-tag-name">Name</div>
  <div class="sub-tag-value">Bob</div>
</div>


<div class="sub-tag-pair">
  <div class="sub-tag-name">Name</div>
  <div class="sub-tag-value">Blah blah .... blah blah ..... test test tset ...A vert vert long name that might break the line on mobile</div>
</div>
```

`flex` element can hold `flex` children too if extra alignement is needed within the children themselves:
example:

```css
.sub-tag-name {
  margin-right: 0;
  padding: 2px 3px 2px 6px;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  background: darkblue;
  color: white;
}

.sub-tag-value {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: 2px 3px 2px 6px;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  color: darkblue
}

.sub-tag-name,
.sub-tag-value {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-color: darkblue;
  
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.sub-tag-pair {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="sub-tag-pair">
  <div class="sub-tag-name">Name</div>
  <div class="sub-tag-value">Bob</div>
</div>


<div class="sub-tag-pair">
  <div class="sub-tag-name">Name</div>
  <div class="sub-tag-value">Blah blah .... blah blah ..... test test tset ...A vert vert long name that might break the line on mobile</div>
</div>
```

You should read : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ to start learn & understand how display flex works and how flex children are layed out ;)

Comment: Sounds great. Is there any way to make the second "name" vertically centered?

Comment: @AGamePlayer I added a snippet and short self explanation ;) (second snippet to run and test)

Comment: Thanks, one more thing, is it possible to make the "Bob" column the same width as the second one (the long one) so that it looks like a tidy table.

Comment: You could add: `flex-grow:1` to the children, they will equally  share  avalaible space or the  full space if alinéa on a row/line.

Comment: thanks a lot! However, I'm still wondering, is there any way that I can change the style of a flex children when it resizes automatically (for instance, in this case the `Blah blah .... blah` element. I want it to change to another color because it's very long. Is there a JavaScript-free way to do that?